# Cannot convert string to generic.enumerable string (CS1503)

Tags: c#

I am currently writing a program that creates a dialog box that asks for input, and then writes the input to a text file. I am having problems with the File.AppendAllLines command. I've tried to switch variables around and change the command, but nothing has worked.

```
DialogResult result = inputBox.ShowDialog();
text1 = textBox.Text;
string text = text1;

File.AppendAllLines(curFile, text);
```

curFile is a variable I defined earlier in the code. Text is the one I'm having issues with. I know its redundant to use text and text1, but I was trying.

Comment: You probably want to use `File.AppendAllText`. `File.AppendAllLines` is expecting an collection of strings, hence the compilation error,

Comment: Pretend for a moment you don't know anything about your task. Read your question. Do you think it contains enough information? You're encountering "problems" but haven't *described* what those problems are.

Comment: What is the relationship between `inputBox` and `textBox`? From what you posted it is not clear why `textBox` should contain text after `inputBox` closes. I would have expected something like `inputBox.Text` or `inputBox.TextBox.Text`.

Answer (score 0):

`File.AppendAllLines` Expect to get a set of text (collection, list, and in .net term `IEnumerable<string>`) and add each one as a separate line in the file.

In your case the lines are already in a single variable, and all that is left to do is add the entire variable content to the file.

so you need use `File.AppendAllText` instaed:

```
File.AppendAllText(curFile, text);
```